# Cannot find type 'ViewController' in scope

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

I am trying to pass data to another ViewController via a segue. Everything was working fine until i decided to change the orignal UIViewController to a TableViewController. Now this issue won't go away. I have changed the view controller class, added the class to storyboard and also ticked the "inherit module from target" box. Iv'e cleaned the build folder and deleted the class file and recreated it. Also i deleted all IBAction function and reconnected.  I'm still getteing the error 'Cannot find type 'CounterViewController' in scope' here:

```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let vc2 = segue.destination as! CounterViewController
    vc2.tallyMax = tallyRange
    }
```

Code above located at the bottom of second view contorler.

ViewController Class 1:

```
import UIKit


class CounterViewController: UIViewController {
    

    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }
    
    var tallyMax:Int = 5
    var buttonCounter:Int = 0
    var buttonTaps:Int = 0
    var buttonTapsDec: Int = 0
    var screeNum1Int:Int = 0
    var screenNum2Int: Int = 0
    var tallyArray: [Int] = [0]
    var tallyIndex: Int = 0
    var tallyConverter:Int = 0
    var arraySwitch:Bool = true
    var i:Int = 0
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var screenNum2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var screenNum1: UILabel!
    
    
    @IBAction func increaseBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        buttonTaps += 1
        screeNum1Int += 1
        if tallyArray.isEmpty{
            tallyArray = [0]
        }
        tallyArray[tallyArray.count - 1] = buttonTaps
        screenNum1.text = String(screeNum1Int)
       // print(tallyArray)
        
        
        // tallyArray[tallyArray.count - 1]
        if  buttonTaps  == tallyMax {
            screenNum2Int = tallyArray.count
            screenNum2.text = String(screenNum2Int)
            buttonTaps = 0
            tallyArray.append(0)
        }
        if screenNum1.text == "9999"{
            reset()
        }
    }
    
    func getTallyScoreindexValue(){
        if tallyArray[tallyArray.count - 1] == tallyMax{
            screenNum2Int = tallyArray.count
            screenNum2.text = String(tallyArray.count)
            //print("Test: \(tallyStore.count)")
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func decreaseBtn(_ sender: Any) {
       
        if screeNum1Int > 0 {
            screeNum1Int -= 1
            screenNum1.text = String(screeNum1Int)
            
            if tallyArray.isEmpty != true{
                buttonTapsDec = tallyArray[tallyArray.count - 1] * tallyMax
                print(buttonTapsDec)
            }
          
            if tallyArray.isEmpty != true{
                if tallyArray[tallyArray.count - 1] > 0 {
                    tallyArray[tallyArray.count - 1] -= 1
                    //print(tallyArray)
                    if tallyArray[tallyArray.count - 1] == tallyMax - 1{
                        screenNum2Int = tallyArray.count - 1
                        screenNum2.text = String(screenNum2Int)
                        //print(screenNum2Int)
                    }
                    if tallyArray[tallyArray.count - 1] == 0 {
                        tallyArray.remove(at: tallyArray.count - 1)
                        
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
            
    }
    
    func reset(){
        screenNum1.text = "0"
        screeNum1Int = 0
        screenNum2Int = 0
        buttonTaps = 0
        screenNum2.text = "0"
        screenNum1.text = String(buttonTaps)
        tallyArray = [0]
        
    }

    @IBAction func reset(_ sender: Any) {
       reset()
    }
    

    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let vc = segue.destination as! SettingsUITableViewControllerX
        
        vc.tallyRange = 5
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func unwindToCounter(unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue){
    }
    
    
}
```

Viewcontroller Class 2:

```
import UIKit


class SettingsUITableViewControllerX: UITableViewController{
    
    var tallyRange:Int = 5
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tallyDisplayLabel.text = String(tallyRange)
    }
    

    @IBOutlet weak var tallyDisplayLabel: UILabel!
    
    
    
   
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let vc2 = segue.destination as! CounterViewController   
        vc2.tallyMax = tallyRange
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Can you check the `Target Membership` of both files?

Comment: found the same issue, did you find any solution?, target membership is same for both files in my case.

Comment: @NeelamVerma u probably can find the answer via ChatGPT.